# Working with Dojo with FixedSplitter with an unwanted outcome

Tags: javascript, dojo

So I'm trying to work with Dojo's FixedSplitter module, and I want it to come out like this:

[image: Working FixedSplitter]

But it's turning out like this:
[image: Not working fxs]

Here's what I'm working with:

```
<body>
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.FixedSplitter" orientation="H">
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.FixedSplitter" data-dojo-props='orientation:"H"'>
          <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Pane" style="background-color:yellow;width:200px;">
            pane #1 (width=200px)
          </div>
          <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Pane" style="background-color:pink;">
            pane #2
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="dojo-release-1.8.1/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true">     </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require([
          "dojox/mobile/parser",
          "dojox/mobile/FixedSplitter",
          "dojox/mobile/Pane"
        ]);
    </script>
</body>
```

I'm new to Dojo, and I have an idea of how things work, but I feel I might be missing something here to make sure that it works properly. It appears to be properly hitting the Javascript file, running the require Javascript fine.

Answer (score 0):

You must apply this css to you html

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```